# How to put the image from the url to a folder the right way in php?

Tags: php

```
    <?php
$img = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pg1dHauUL._SL75_.jpg';
$target_path = 'product-images/';
$target_path= $target_path.basename($img);

if(move_uploaded_file($img,$target_path)){
    echo '<br>Success.';
}
else {
    echo '<br>Error.';
}
?>
```

I don't know what is wrong, I think my path is correct.

Comment: full coding will be better? and what error do you get?

Comment: that's all my code..and if it works there should be image in my folder

Comment: If any solution given works perfectly, please tick it as correct answer below the vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```
    <?php
    $img = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pg1dHauUL._SL75_.jpg';
    $target_path = 'CHANGEYOURPATH/CHANGEYOURIMAGENAME.CHANGEYOUREXTENSION';

if (file_put_contents($target_path, file_get_contents($img)))
{
    echo "Success";
}

else
{
    echo "Error!";
}



 // EXAMPLE

    $img = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pg1dHauUL._SL75_.jpg';
        $target_path = 'C:\TEST\image.jpg';
        file_put_contents($target_path, file_get_contents($img));
        ?>
```